# How to configure Symfony 5 service parameters during functional test?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony5

One of my routes under test uses a Service and this Service has a parameter set in `services.yml`.

In production mode everything works as expected but I would like to change the value of `$my_arg` while running tests.

How can I do this? How do I set the value of a Symfony 5 service parameter during a functional test?

This is an extract from my `services.yml` configuration:

```
parameters:
    app.my_param: 'foo'

services:
    ...
    App\Service\MyService:
        arguments:
            $my_arg: '%app.my_param%'
```

Comment: Do you use phpunit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is **environment dependant**, I would use an **environment variable** to store it.

You can even set a default value in case you only need to override it in specific environments.

```
parameters:
    env(APP_MY_PARAM): 'foo'
    app.my_param: '%env(APP_MY_PARAM)%'

services:
    ...
    App\Service\MyService:
        arguments:
            $my_arg: '%app.my_param%'
```

You now only need to set the environment variable `APP_MY_PARAM` to change the application behaviour.

The easiest way to accomplish this for test, is to create a `.env.test` file:

```
#.env.test
APP_MY_PARAM=bar
```

With this, `$my_arg` will be set as `"bar"` during testing, and as `"foo"` by default if you do not set the environment variable to anything else.

Comment: I have implemented this guidance and it works very well.

Comment: Are we saying that symfony5 has done away with environment based configuration? In symfony4 we used to have config files for each environment.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that.